# How to make the first User an admin with ability file (cancan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
user ||= User.new 
if user.admin == 1 #admin
    can :manage, :all
elsif 
  user.id != nil # registred users
  can :read, :all
  can :create, Post
  cannot :manage, User
else
   can :read, :all # guest user (not logged in)
   cannot :manage, User

end
```

Here is my ability file. I want it to make the first registered user the admin and give them all the permissions to edit the whole web page, whilst the User has limited access to only managing Posts and a guest User is only allowed to read posts. However when I use 
    if can? in my code, the admin is given the same amount of access as a normal user. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the user you are passing to initialize is *in fact* an admin? I would drop a logging call as the first line with `user.inspect` to make sure I have an admin user. Secondly, have you tried `if user.admin?`.  I'm assuming it's a boolean field rather than integer.

Answer (score 0):

In my work I have to do the same thing but with Company.

Every Company creation I check if is the first, if it is, I set it as admin, otherwise, normal user.

The `if can?` is used here to define if a menu will be hidden or visible. With only that, the user will still access the page if he types the URL so you need to add `load_and_authorize_resource` so the user gets a message about not having permission.

Is that what you need? =)